# Can I have multiple inputs in a Embedded Python Block?

Tags: python, input, block, gnuradio

I'd like to know If I could have an Embedded Python Block with multiples inputs? If the answer is yes, How could I get it?
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just use several blocks ?

Comment: Hi, Because I've to perfom the same processing operation with multiple inputs and get a single output

Answer (score 2):

To have multiple inputs you need to add more elements to the `in_sig` parameter. For example to have two complex inputs you need `in_sig=[np.complex64, np.complex64]`

```py
class blk(gr.sync_block):  # other base classes are basic_block, decim_block, interp_block
    """Embedded Python Block example - a simple multiply const"""

    def __init__(self, example_param=1.0):  # only default arguments here
        """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Embedded Python Block',   # will show up in GRC
            in_sig=[np.complex64, np.complex64],
            out_sig=[np.complex64]
        )
```

See also [3.2.3. Modifying the Python Block File](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_Python#3.2.3._Modifying_the_Python_Block_File).

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I tried your modification and It worked.

Comment: @ClaudiaTorresPerez Then you should validate the answer!